# Print input value to different DIVS- jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, input

I am currently working on a little project as I am new to jQuery.

I have 4 little DIVS on my page with different IDS from div1-div4. On the top of the page I have a INPUT where the user will be able to write name of the DIV user want to use different functions on. After the first input there is another input where the user will be able to write a text which will be printed in to the DIV which is chosen in the first input with the help of a "Add Text" button.

After that I have 4 different buttons which are Fade Out, Fade In, Slide Up, Slide Down.

These functions will only work on the div ID which the user have written in the first box.

Here is an JQuery example of one of my functions:

```
$("#fadeOutBtn").click(function(){

selectedDiv = $('#divChooseTxt').val();
$("#"+selectedDiv).fadeOut(1500, "swing", function(){

        });
    });
```

What I need help with now is to understand how to get the text from the user and print that to the selected DIV.

Here is the HTML for this function:

```
<label>Text: 
<input id="divTxt" type="text">
</label>
<input id="addTextBtn" type="button" value="Add Text">
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/yc4ahsno/

Get the text with val():

```
test = $('#divTxt').val();
```

Insert the text into a div:

```
document.getElementById('thisdiv').innerHTML = test;
```

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/yc4ahsno/3/      document.getElementById(selectedDiv).innerHTML = 'You chose this div';

Comment: Your user enters the div name and you want to perform changes to that div after the submit button is pressed, correct? Why would you not be able to that with the code provided? You wrote 'What I need help with now is to understand how to get the text from the user and print that to the selected DIV.' With those functions you can get the text and print it. Try to update your code first and see where you still have problems.

Comment: Your function won't work as the divs you provided in your html have different names, so I wrote a new one. You can simply adjust your Code to achieve what you want.

Comment: The text of the div the user wrote will get updated with that text so he knows which one was selected. It's just an example, you will need to adjust your code according to those examples to get it to work the way you want.

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/yc4ahsno/4/ here's a version with the html changed to the names you use in your function. They need to be the same or else it won't work at all.

Comment: You wrote  document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = test; this needs to be  document.getElementById(selectedDiv).innerHTML = test; to update the div you wrote in the text field. Look at this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/yc4ahsno/8/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Next step is to utilize the function within the switch statement as well.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/5rczkw7h/)

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var content = $('#content').val();
    $('#results').html(name);
    functions(name,content);
});
function functions(name,content){
    switch(name){
        case 'a':
            $('#div_one').css('background-color','red');
            $('#div_one').html(content);
            break;
            case 'b':
            $('#div_two').css('background-color','red');
            $('#div_two').html(content);
            break;
            case 'c':
            $('#div_three').css('background-color','red');
            $('#div_three').html(content);
            break;
            case 'd':
            $('#div_four').css('background-color','red');
            $('#div_four').html(content);
            break;

    }
}
```

The switch statement takes the input and matches the correct functionality to it.